# how to find specific class through all child elements and if available then hide that child element?

Tags: jquery

I have one scenario, where I have to go through all the child elements and check if there is a specific class is available or not. If it's available, then hide that specific element. This is my html code:

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="topnav"></li>
        <li class="topnav"></li>
        <li class="topnav"></li>        
        <li class="topnav all"></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Now, I am able to check if any child elements has class `all` or not, using this code:

```
$('#toolbar ul').find('li').hasClass('all')
```

And I am getting `true`. Now, I want to hide that specific element, which has `all` class. I have tried with this code:

```
if($('#toolbar ul').find('li').hasClass('all')) $(this).hide();
```

But, didn't get success. So, kindly guide me here, on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `.find(".all").hide()`?

Comment: `$(this)` has no reason to point to that specific element here (unless there’s more context to this, that you neglected to tell us about.) Just call hide on the selector you used to find the element. This doesn’t even need a check via if - just select the element(s) and hide them. If there are not elements in the selection, then simply nothing will happen.

Comment: @RichardMauritz, thank you. I didn't know this approach. It worked.

Comment: Allright, i make an awser of it, So people know it has been awnsered and for people who come here to find any ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close with the following code
`$('#toolbar ul').find('li').hasClass('all')`

Just change that one line into this
`$('#toolbar ul').find('.all').hide()`

That will hide all descendants inside the `ul` with the classname `.all`

> **.find():** Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.